# How can I display a key's data from mongoose document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am querying the mongo collection by key.

```
const sampleFeedback = await Feedback.findById("610e2fe1bb8d62053de5f37b");
```

below is screenshot on data in MongoDB:

[image]

the data I get in sampleFeedback is below:

```
{
  _id: 610e2fe1bb8d62053de5f37b,
  questionOne: { 'Very good': 0, Satisfactory: 0, Poor: 0 }
}
```

I am not able to access object stored in `questionOne` key

I have tried below statements, all result in {} or undefined

```
console.log(Object(sampleFeedback['questionOne']));
console.log(sampleFeedback['questionOne']);

console.log(sampleFeedback[questionOne]);

console.log(sampleFeedback.questionOne);
```

Comment: 1) what are you getting when you `console.log(sampleFeedback)` 2) can you show schema for this collection?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, there was a typo in the schema which i fixed and it's running